# Remove Duplicate records without using DISTINCT and GROUP BY keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter-3

I have one query below where I have used codeigniter active record class. I'm getting duplicate records so I was wondering how could solve without the use of group by and distinct.

```
$this->db->select(array('tblilots_proposal.id', 'buyer', 'offer_price', 'tblilots_proposal.units', 'tblilots_proposal.status', 'tblilots_proposal.date_added as proposal_date', 'tblilots_clients_plan.unit_price', 'ilots_stage_id', 'slot', 'tblilots_clients_plan.date_added as purchased_date', 'tblilots_plan_details.roi_pct', 'tblilots_plan_details.roi_period', 'value_pct', 'value_period', 'duration_num', 'duration_period'));
$this->db->from('tblilots_proposal');
$this->db->join('tblilots_clients_plan', 'tblilots_clients_plan.id = tblilots_proposal.ilots_clients_planid');
$this->db->join('tblilots_plan_details', 'tblilots_plan_details.ilots_fieldid = tblilots_clients_plan.ilots_field_id');
$this->db->join('tblilots_stage', 'tblilots_stage.id = tblilots_clients_plan.ilots_stage_id');
$this->db->where('userid', get_client_user_id());
$proposal = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: *"Below is my query that I have used. It works as expected"* i have a doubt about that as using functional dependecy can only really be trusted in MySQL 5.7.5 + , see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) .. Also GROUP BY is not designed to filter out duplicates..

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you are looking for. You want to select distinct records, but you don't want to use `distinct` (why not? That's what its there for), so instead you misuse `group_by` and are looking for an alternative (again, why?)

Comment: Actually the company I work for said not to use group by and distinct. So I'm looking for some alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask around your company, then.

Comment: If that was possible then I would n't ask a question here.

Comment: Well then start with what current comment #2 suggests, because otherwise your question _can_ in all likelihood not even be answered. We don’t know what result you consider “correct” here, all we can see is that your query _contains fundamental errors to begin with._ You are asking us for “other ways” to reproduce a result that was created in a bogus way in the first place, so that we can not even know what it is you actually want.

Comment: I just want to get distinct records. If you tell me where my query is wrong then it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Does your company have a reason not to use `group_by` or `distinct`?  How can we help if we do not know the seemingly arbetary criteria given by "The Company"?

Comment: Right now I only see SQL is an issue, but not PHP. Otherwise use PHP code to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: can you tell me what's the issue in the sql??